# How to get shortest path between source and destination

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

My Mysql table consist as follows

[image]

I want to get shortest path from here. I tried 'WITH RECURSIVE' way. but it gives mysql error. Is there any way of doing that? I want to list items which gives shortest path.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY distance DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @Strawberry, I guess he means shortest path between any two nodes.

Comment: @Aashishgaba The OP is welcome to improve their question.

Comment: yes, i need to get shortest path. When i have origin and destination points, i want to know which way i can go with less time when there is more ways to go.

Comment: It seems that this is more an algorithm question than a MySQL one. Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: I read those, but i don't have idea of doing this in mysql. please help me

Comment: The `WITH RECURSIVE` syntax is a new feature in MySQL 8.0. If you use an older version of MySQL, you can't use recursive queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but note that this scales abysmally poorly for larger data sets...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,origin VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,destination VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,distance INT NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(origin,destination)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'MILAN','TURIN',150),
(2,'TURIN','MILAN',150),

(3,'MILAN','VENICE',250),
(4,'VENICE','MILAN',250),

(5,'MILAN','GENOA',200),

(6,'MILAN','ROME',600),
(7,'ROME','MILAN',600),

(8,'MILAN','FLORENCE',380),

(9,'TURIN','GENOA',160),
(10,'GENOA','TURIN',160),

(11,'FLORENCE','VENICE',550),

(12,'FLORENCE','ROME',220),
(13,'ROME','FLORENCE',220);

SELECT x.origin
     , y.origin waypoint1
     , z.origin waypoint2
     , COALESCE(z.destination,y.destination,x.destination) destination
     , x.distance+COALESCE(y.distance,0)+COALESCE(z.distance,0) distance
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.origin = x.destination
   AND y.destination <> x.origin
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table z
    ON z.origin = y.destination
   AND z.destination <> y.origin
   AND z.destination <> x.origin
 WHERE x.origin = 'ROME'
HAVING destination = 'VENICE'
 ORDER  
    BY distance LIMIT 1;
    
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| origin | waypoint1 | waypoint2 | destination | distance |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| ROME   | MILAN     | NULL      | VENICE      |      850 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggesstion, i'm able to get some correct output. but i have problem, what if there is more waypoints than 2? here we connect only 2. but there can be more.

Comment: Yes , longer routes equals more joins. I answered the question asked.

Comment: can it add dynamically?

Comment: Not the way I've written it, but I think it a little  unlikely that you'd need more than 6 or 8 joins to get the shortest distance between A and B